# Database of user agents

Tags: software

I'm looking for list of web browser user agents for testing purposes. Ideally in some common text format. Especially for the desktop and mobile devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The User Agent Project](http://theafh.net/the-user-agents-project/) is a research project consisting of a comprehensive list of unique user agent strings compiled since 2006. The UA Project is accessible as a [specialized search engine](http://ua.theafh.net/).

[Browscap](https://github.com/browscap/browscap)'s repository includes a [User Agent Database Resource](https://github.com/browscap/browscap/wiki/Resource:-User-Agents-Database), althouth the wiki hasn't been updated since 2015. Browscap has had updates as recently as 2017-06, but that includes the entire repository, not just the ua db.

[Udger UA List Database](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list) "includes detailed information about ever(y) single user agent and operating system".

[User Agent String.Com](http://www.useragentstring.com/) has a [large list of user agent strings by ua type](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php), and offers [an API](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php)

[User-Agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org/) has a [List of User-Agents (Spiders, Robots, Crawlers, Browser)](http://www.user-agents.org/allagents.xml) in XML format, as well as a search database and some other offerings.

Answer (score 2):

I've found so far this: [Massive list of user agents for User Agent Switcher by Chris Pederik](https://web.archive.org/web/20180424023135/https://gist.github.com/enginnr/ed572cf5c324ad04ff2e).

It's in XML format and it's grouped based on the browser and the device type. It has 602 entries.

Here are some other copies:

- https://gist.github.com/javidrashid/9079cf0073cca7383269dbbdcc80e5b6
- https://gist.github.com/kenorb/40df55940a9543e3c4158679219f063a
- https://gist.github.com/search?l=XML&q=useragentswitcher

Here is the shell command dumping printing this list in plain format:

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/javidrashid/9079cf0073cca7383269dbbdcc80e5b6/raw/55c1c6ac3185553c0063674fd8e594988e7b257c/useragentswitcher.xml | grep -o 'useragent=.[^"]\+"'
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/user-agents - this solves a lot of the issues.

> User-Agents is a JavaScript package for generating random User Agents based on how frequently they're used in the wild. A new version of the package is automatically released every day, so the data is always up to date. The generated data includes hard to find browser-fingerprint properties, and powerful filtering capabilities allow you to restrict the generated user agents to fit your exact needs.

To install, for example with yarn

```
# With yarn: 
yarn add user-agents
```

Example code:

```
import UserAgent from 'user-agents';

const userAgent = new UserAgent();
console.log(userAgent.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify(userAgent.data, null, 2));
```

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

I just used this github repo which has either a sample list ([N=100](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kenjis/user-agent-parser-benchmarks/master/data/ua-list-100-sample01.txt)) or the full thing ([N=437](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kenjis/user-agent-parser-benchmarks/master/data/ua-list-all.txt))

https://github.com/kenjis/user-agent-parser-benchmarks/tree/master/data

(you can ignore the rest of the php stuff in the repo)